# Was HMS Cumberland of 1748-1750 a fireship?

Tags: england, navy, ship, 1750s, 1740s

At [Were 18th century British mariners incentivized to serve aboard fireships?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15887/were-18th-century-british-mariners-incentivized-to-serve-aboard-fireships) I am assuming that my candidate 6th great grandfather Jeremiah was a Steward of the ship *Cumberland* from 7 Mar 1748 to 22 Aug 1750, and that the Cumberland was a fireship.

Comments on that question have raised some doubts as to whether this particular *Cumberland* was actually a fireship after all.

How can I establish that the *Cumberland* he served upon was (or was not) a fireship?

Answer (score 2):

One clue I would consider is the rank mentioned for the individual in the linked question. The Steward in 18th century British navy was a civil position, hired by the Captain.  If we look at Wikipedia page describing [Royal Navy Ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Navy_ranks,_rates,_and_uniforms_of_the_18th_and_19th_centuries) and look at the description in the entry for Steward:

> A more senior cook and servant, ***usually reserved for flagships and
>   larger vessels***

A [66-gun third rank ship-of-the-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Cumberland_(1710)) might have a Steward, whereas it would be less likely on an 8-gun fireship.